# How To Prevent Circular Relationships In Model?

Tags: alloy

I'm working with Alloy 6 and I'm attempting to model a system to create packages for various package managers.  For example the system might create a Rebar3 (Package) for maybe ChocolateyNuget and Flatpak (Package Managers). If there are other packages which need to be installed (e. g. Erlang) that'd be a dependency.

This is the model I've come up with so far:

```
module assembler3

some sig Package{
   dependencies: this -> some Package
}
{
   // Package cannot be its own dependency
   no p:Package | p in p.^(dependencies)
}

some sig PackageManager{
   packages: set Package
}

fact "A package cannot belong to more than one package manager" {
   //A package can only belong to one package manager
   all p: Package |
      one pm: PackageManager |
         p in pm.packages
}
```

And this is one of the potential instances:

[image: Possible Instance of Model]

As you can see from the potential instance as my model stands right now I can have Package1 dependent on Package2 and Package2 dependent on Package1.  I want to prevent this kind of circular relationship but I can't quite figure out how to express the constraint.  Would someone please suggest how I might find the right constraint to prevent a circular relationship between package dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

I think the `dependencies` relation is not well defined, it does not require a `this ->`. A field is a relation between the parent (Package) and the field. So it should be:

```
dependencies : set Package
```

Your constraint is then also different:

```
this not in this.^@dependencies
```

The `@` is needed to prevent applying the automatic `this` join for associated rules to a sig.

You can also reduce the complexity of the model by declaring the relation between the `Package` and the `PackageManager` as a mandatory field inside the Package. Then you do not need a fact to enforce this, which is imho always better.

```
module assembler3

some sig PackageManager{}

some sig Package{
    manager     : PackageManager,
    dependencies: set Package
}  {
    this not in this.^@dependencies
}
```

A further simplification is not to have Package Managers. For a dependency problem,the actual package manager tends to be an attribute of the package, not a relation.